# What do we mean by singleton class in objective c? Is it similar to nonatomic property or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile

Can we call every nonatomic property as a singleton class?

Please explain nonatomic property and singleton class along with their differences and similarities.

Comment: Have you gone through web? There are many tutorials, blogs etc that will help you. Please search properly before asking a question.

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to imporove this question. I have a question ban because of this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Main similarity between them is both are **THREAD-SAFE**

Check these links for a good idea of singleton classes

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTfEN8KQPK8 (Example video)

Answer (score 3):

The Singleton pattern is a design pattern found in Objective C. What are design patterns? A design pattern is a pattern implemented to get an application to work more efficiently or as a solution to an existing problem. The Objective C Singleton pattern lets you enforce only one instance for a given class. This class can be accessed globally through a global access point. The first time this class is accessed, a new instance of the class will be created. For example, if you are building an application and declare a singleton class, the same instance of the class will be accessible by all the elements in your application. A new instance of the class will never be created. This helps you save on system memory and space. It also prevents redundant code.

**And it is not similar to nonatomic property**

See example

Singalton.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobleDirector : NSObject
+(GlobleDirector*)shareManager;
@end
```

Singalton class .m file

```
#import "GlobleDirector.h"

@implementation GlobleDirector


+(GlobleDirector*)shareManager{

static GlobleDirector *sharedInstance=nil;
static dispatch_once_t  oncePredecate;

dispatch_once(&oncePredecate,^{
sharedInstance=[[GlobleDirector alloc] init];

});
return sharedInstance;
}



@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Single tone class mean you make this class as globel to program. you make shared object of this class that mean this is not allocated again.
ex:-

```
In FBIntegration.h
+(FBIntegration*)sharedFBIntegrationClass;


In FBIntegration.m

static FBIntegration* __FBIntegration;

+(FBIntegration*)sharedFBIntegrationClass
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(!__FBIntegration) {
            __FBIntegration = [[[self class] alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return __FBIntegration;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Singleton]

The above image shows a Logger class with a single property (which is the single instance), and two methods: sharedInstance and init.
The first time a client sends the sharedInstance message, the property instance isn’t yet initialized, so you create a new instance of the class and return a reference to it.
The next time you call sharedInstance, instance is immediately returned without any initialization. This logic promises that only one instance exists at all times and the method we used is called Singleton Method.

Adding a singleton method in your class doesn't make your class, a singleton. You can say you have implemented a singleton method in your class. If you want to create a singleton class, you need to override all the init functions, so as to ensure that we can only create the single instance of that class. Then only we can say it is a singleton class or generally we say strictly singleton.

Example :

```
+ (instancetype)singleton {
    static id singletonInstance = nil;
    if (!singletonInstance) {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            singletonInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        });
    }
    return singletonInstance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [self singleton];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}
```

Singleton doesn't mean that the class is global in your program, it is a pattern for keeping the single instance of a class throughout the program.